# objective-c animations - how to set end position, direction and type

Tags: objective-c, animation

I've seen many examples and read tutorial on animations, 
all examples look +- the same like so:

```
- (void)showAnimation
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f animations:^{
        backgroundView.alpha = 1.0f;
    }];


    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f
                          delay:0.0f
         usingSpringWithDamping:0.4f
          initialSpringVelocity:0.0f
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                     animations:^{
                         CATransform3D init = CATransform3DIdentity;
                         alertView.layer.transform = init;

                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         if( [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(alertViewDidAppear:)] && finished) {
                             [self.delegate alertViewDidAppear:self];
                         }
                     }];
}
```

what I'm failing to understand is in the animation block where:
1. I set the beginning position
2. set the end position
3. the direction of movement
4. type of animation (fly-in/ turn/ fade-in/appear etc.)

Answer (score 1):

There is no "starting position". There is no "direction of movement" or "type of animation". Animation is a change over time. The view is a certain way at the time your code runs. UIView animation has 6 possible view properties. You change any of those in the animation block (which states the time) and the change is animated - that is, instead of the change just happening, kaboom, it is performed over the given time.

That's all there is to it (as far as UIView class-method animation is concerned).